# How many different ways to split a set of poker into exactly 6 groups? And what might be the simplest way to solve this?

Tags: poker

Well it's a simple question but I was wondering if there is a simpler way to solve this kind of question than Monte Carlo?

Comment: What is "a set of poker"?  You're missing some words here.

Comment: a set of poker means 54 cards

Comment: Ok, I'd call that "a deck of cards with two jokers". Most poker games don't use jokers, but it's your game. Now, you want to divide that deck into six hands--nine cards each (to exhaust the deck), or just five cards each, as in poker?

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify. The game is to calc how many ways one can divide 54 cards (no matter it is joker or ace or whatever, for this game the only focus is to calculate how many ways to divide the cards, so you can even treat those cards as if they are identical to each other.) into 6 hands. So the combination could be anything from [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9] to [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 49] without considering the order within the combination.